# filtering arraylist of object using addTextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext, android-filter

I am trying to filter my arraylist of song info where i am retrieving data from internal storage.I am able to show the filter data in my adapter but how can i use the filter method to filter from the arraylist .I tried some post but are realy very old now and not working in my case.`I want to pass the filtered data but the arraylist is not getting filtered ,But i am able to show the filtered data in adapter.`
here is what i tried.

```
   private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private  ArrayList<Songfileinfo> newlist;
private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songarr = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkReadStoragePermission();
    Songdata load = new Songdata();
    this.songarr = load.getPlayList(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, getPlaylist());
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.e("size",""+newlist.size());
        }
    });
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}


private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> getPlaylist() {
     newlist = new ArrayList<Songfileinfo>();
    Songfileinfo songfileinfo;
    for (int i = 0; i < songarr.size(); i++) {
        Log.v("SiZE OF IMG ARR", "" + songarr.get(i).getAlbum_art());
        songfileinfo = new Songfileinfo(songarr.get(i).getTitle(), songarr.get(i).getAlbum(),
                songarr.get(i).getAlbum_art(), songarr.get(i).getArtist(), songarr.get(i).getFile_uri(), songarr.get(i).getDuration());

        newlist.add(songfileinfo);
    }
    return newlist;
}
```

My custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> display;
private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> searcharr;
private final Typeface typeface;
CustomFilter customFilter;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songarr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.display = songarr;
    this.searcharr = songarr;
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return display.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return display.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return display.indexOf(getItem(pos));
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_songlist, null);

    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    textView.setText(display.get(pos).getTitle());
    textView1.setText(display.get(pos).getAlbum());

    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    textView1.setTypeface(typeface);
    long timer = 0;

    timer = Long.parseLong(display.get(pos).getDuration());
    textView2.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer(timer));
    textView2.setTypeface(typeface);
    Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(display.get(pos).getAlbum_art()))
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .fitCenter()
            .error(R.drawable.music)

            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(circleImageView);

    return convertView;
}

public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";

    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if (hours > 0) {
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }

    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
        secondsString = "" + seconds;
    }

    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (customFilter == null) {
        customFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return customFilter;
}


class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
            charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<Songfileinfo> filter = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < searcharr.size(); i++) {
                if (searcharr.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)) {
                    Songfileinfo songfileinfo = new Songfileinfo(searcharr.get(i).getTitle(), searcharr.get(i).getAlbum(), searcharr.get(i).getAlbum_art(), searcharr.get(i).getArtist(), searcharr.get(i).getFile_uri(), searcharr.get(i).getDuration());
                    filter.add(songfileinfo);
                }
            }
            filterResults.count = filter.size();
            filterResults.values = filter;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = searcharr.size();
            filterResults.values = searcharr;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        display = (ArrayList<Songfileinfo>) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

I tried to get the size and the size remain the same ,I know I have to make a new arraylist but how can i use the filter or the textchangelistener to make a new arraylist.Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<Songfileinfo> { ...` and override its `onBind` and `matches` methods

Comment: ya i am using a custom adapter and i am able to show the the filter data in adapter but how can i filter the arraylist

Comment: the same way: `customAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);`, also no need for `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I want to filter arraylist of object sir .So how can i use the filter method for my arraylist object

Comment: Sir see the update question

Comment: so did you try to use a custom `MatchableArrayAdapter`?

Comment: ya sir in my case its the CustomAdapter is ur MatchableArrayAdapter

Comment: ok so what problems do you have with a custom `MatchableArrayAdapter`?

Comment: sir i want to filter the arraylist also so i can pass the data to my service class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137286/discussion-between-neelay-srivastava-and-pskink).